# Alternative for count distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want an alternative way to write the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1) FROM table.
```

I dont want to use `distinct`. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: But... You... Apparently... want... a count of... the distinct values. Why do you want to avoid `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Performance issues with using distinct.

Comment: How about group by then coumt?

Comment: Then deal with the performance issues - look for missing indexes, etc. SQL isn't (generally) a language with booby traps built in where the obvious solution will perform badly but some magical incantation will produce good performance.

Comment: @SagarTandel It's unlikely that there will be any performance difference. The same work needs to be done either way. Why do you think it'll make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY` as a subquery and `COUNT()` from outside query. It would achieve same result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Col1
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Col1
) tbl
```

Comment: I agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever in his comment to the question. 
Look at the execution plans to find the reason for bad performance (e.g. missing index, etc.). SQL is a declarative language, the database engine creates a physical execution plan that determines how the query will be executed. In many cases, the execution plan will be the same even if you try using different SQL syntax for same objective. I've executed both queries (this one and the original with DISTINCT) and I get the same execution plan for both of them (so there is no performance difference between them).

Comment: @saso: I certainly agree with Damien but I am just showing the OP the alternative for the query he was asking.

Comment: You're right. My comment was actually intended for the original poster as I believe he's looking for a solution to his problem in the wrong "place". Sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(col1) from table GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: This query is returning different data. The OP wants to count the number of distinct values in a column (a scalar value), your query is returning something else: a count of records for each distinct col1 value, e.g. how many times a certain col1 value appears in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(Col1)   
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) As RNO, Col1
        FROM Table_Name)  
WHERE  RNO = 1
```

Comment: There is a trap when you using window functions. For example, if you want to group then by some field of the row which is not first, you get null or 0. 

Example. 
You have some check in a shop. Then you add some goods to your basket. They added in some order, but id of the check is the same. If you want to count all checks, it's ok, they will be counted properly, but if you want then group checks by goods, checks will be counted only for first good, because the RNO of the first good will be 1